Compatibility of 2-copulas
An $n$-copula is the joint distribution function of a distribution on $[0,1]^n$ with uniform marginals. A family of 2-copulas $(C_{i,j})_{i<j\leq n}$ is compatible if there exists an $n$-copula $\tilde C$ with bivariate marginals $(C_{i,j})_{i<j\leq n}$, i.e.
$$\tilde C(1,\dots,1, \underbrace{u}_i, \dots, \underbrace{j}_i, 1, \dots, 1) = C_{i,j}(u,v), \quad u,v\in[0,1], i<j\leq n.$$
In the case $n = 3$ it is known that given any two 2-copulas there is a third on making the three compatible. In particular, given $A := C_{1,2}, B := C_{2,3}$ and a (measurable) family of 2-copulas $\mathcal C = (\mathcal C_t)_{t\in [0,1]}$ the following defines a 2-copula making the family $(C_{i,j})$ compatible
$$C_{1,3}(u,v) = (A \star_{\mathcal C} B)(u,v) = \int_0^1 \mathcal C_t(\partial_2 A(u,t), \partial_1 B(t,v))\,dt.$$
What is known in the case $n > 3$? In particular:

How many "degrees of freedom" exists, i.e. how many bivariate marginals can be specified before restrictions have to be placed?
Given "degrees of freedom"-many 2-copulas, is there a way to construct the remaining bivariate marginals? (I'm not claiming uniqueness here)

This may or may not an open problem. I'm not familiar with this area, so I'm mostly trying to ascertain whether this is the case.
